# Right way of running a root task/program at background

Tags: root, shutdown, background-process

I'm writing a program that needs to run at the background as root.

(for any user)

To do this I used the `/etc/rc.local` file. And it seems to work.

The problem that I am experiencing is, when a normal user tries to
turn off the computer, since there is an active "task" from the root account,
the normal user is propped to enter the root password.

This made me guessing that I'm probably doing this in a wrong way. Is there any better way of doing this?  I've thought in some fixes that may work but I would really like to know how to properly do this!

Comment: Which distro do you use? Mine (openSUSE) asks the user for confirmation (not the password) if there are other logins. So probably this behaviour can be configured.

Comment: @HaukeLaging I'm using Debian Wheezy. After cheeking the answer of Peter, it seems that it is something caused by my program. Maybe I could configure the behavior as you say, but I should better find the bug on my program!, Anyways thanks for posting a solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It doesn't depend on it. If you call a simple task from rc.local, you shouldn't get this behavior.

If you want to run a task as root in the background: this is what is called as daemons. There are more methods to do that, the 3 most probable:

1. If the demon does something periodically, you can develop it as a [crontab](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab%205) script. It is very clear, although not really effective.
2. You can create a service for that too, which mean: 1. you had to develop its start/stop script in `/etc/inittab`, and 2. you had to configure the service with your systemd (which is probably your main system service starter/restarter daemon). If here you had problem, your next questions are welcomed.
3. The most robust solutions are coming by combining the previous 2. Although it combines the fallbacks, too. You implement a system service, runs it as a system service, and develops a tester script too, which only tests if it work correctly. If not, then kills and restarts.

About your actual problem: no, user will be prompted almost surely not because a simple running daemon. It must be somewhere others in your settings. On a normal system there is around some hundred processes, and practically there are always tasks which can't be stopped cleanly (either because of some problem, or because it isn't needed, or because it is impossible). It doesn't cause problematic behavior on the systems, only makes the reboots faster. If you elaborated a little bit which distro do you use, what are you running in the background etc. it helped us a lot.

Comment: These days one usually doesn't need to perform the checking manually - modern init systems (launchd, OpenRC, systemd - in alphabetic order) have that capability natively.

Comment: @peterph Thank you the extension. Maybe they can check the existence of a process, but surely they can't do some functional test (for example, downloading a php test page to make sure an apache/php system yet works).

Comment: Certainly not by default. On the other hand a failed page download doesn't tell you whether the webserver needs a restart or whether it is just temporarily under very heavy load. It can even make such problems worse. :)

Comment: @peterph Yes, it is true.

Comment: Instead of calling my program I made a simple script, and you are right, I don't get the message when shutting off the computer. The answer is pretty helpful, thanks!